# Instead of rendering page HTML content is rendering in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I made one 404 error page in my project. It works well in local. But when I deploy it on live only just this 404 error page render html content other pages works well. When I test it on local this 404 error page render as expected it not shows any html content. So my question is why on live site it render html content? How to resolve this issue? Please help.

Comment: are you using `IIS` to host your site?

Comment: Yes, I am using IIS

Comment: you're exposing your nr-data credentials in the screenshot..is that alright to be shared?

Comment: I removed it. But how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check your `web.config` file and see if you've included following section or not...

```
  <system.web>
    <customErrors defaultRedirect="~/ErrorController" mode="On">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/ErrorController/ErrorPage" />
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
```

`ErrorController/ErrorPage` will need to be replaced with your error controller and error page action.

EDIT: Also ensure your `FilterConfig` registers `filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());`